# Is there is any additional settings in asterisk to get calls consistently from sonetel?

Tags: asterisk, trunk

I have a sonetel trunk in asterisk. When I make a call, sometimes it is not reaching asterisk correctly. Is there is any additional settings in asterisk to get calls consistently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding two trunks for sonetel in asterisk